# getRespondentEmail() generates a script failure even though it returns the respondents email address

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a weird issue with getRespondentEmail(). I have a Google Form, manually created. The "collect email addresses" option is ticked. Attached to the form is a script. Here's the first bit of it:

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  var responder = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  Logger.log(responder)
 var formResponse = e.response.getItemResponses();
```

The form can be submitted, responses are captured, the onSubmit function runs and I can see in my Logger the correct email address from the form response. So why do I receive a "Summary of failures for Google Apps Script" email containing the following error?

```
TypeError: Cannot find function getRespondentEmail in object [object Object]...
```

Is it a glitch that will go away or have I missed something?

Thanks

Comment: I tested your code out with my own form, and it was working well, I would suggest you change the name of your function, perhaps it is treating it as a trigger itself. If you don't have it, you should have it as an on form submit  [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). If you already have it set up this way, then it might be a glitch, try again today and if you keep receiving the error emails, there might be a bug.

Comment: Thanks. I do have a trigger set: "From form - On form submit" calling the function "onSubmit". I thought the function had to be called onSubmit to work. I try changing it as it could be that it's picking up that function name automatically an running my script twice.

Comment: In general you can have the function named the same as the trigger, this is what's called a [Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/), it generally has less capabilities than the Installable Triggers (the ones you made with the UI).

Comment: Thanks. I do have a trigger set: "From form - On form submit" calling the function "onSubmit". I thought the function had to be called onSubmit to work. 

I changed my function name and the script still ran successfully but I still got the error email referencing the old function name so clearly a bug somewhere.

How does one report a bug and is it even worthwhile?

Comment: Operator error. There was a second onSubmit function attached to the form responses sheet that was running as well. I removed it and now got an error saying function not found. I'm a little confused about what's running where but at least I've found where the problem is. 
Thanks for your help AMolina.

Comment: That explains it, what you can do is check the existing installed triggers and the functions you have in the code to make sure that only what you wan is running, but I'm glad it's solved!